# Integral of $\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1}$

Tags: integration

I know the formula$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1} = \tan^{-1}(x) + C$$

But, when integrating by parts:

$$u = x^2+1$$
$$u' = 2x$$

$$v' = 1$$
$$v = x$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1} = uv - \int vu' dx = x(x^2+1) - \int 2x^2dx$$
$$ \int 2x^2dx = \frac{2x^3}{3} + C$$

So, finally: $$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1} = x(x^2+1) - \frac{2x^3}{3} + C$$

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are:

$$ u = x^2+1 $$ 
This seems a little fishy, notice that this part is in fraction?!? If you want to use partial integration you should have used:

$$ u = \frac{1}{x^2+1} $$

Answer (score 4):

Integration by parts tells us that:

> $$
> \int u v' \, dx = uv - \int vu' \, dx
> $$

What you did was:
$$
\int \frac{v'}{u} \, dx \neq uv - \int vu' \, dx
$$

Answer (score 3):

Look this is an easier approach: Put $x = \tan \alpha $ . then $dx = \sec^2 \alpha d \alpha $. Hence

$$ \int \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} = \int \frac{\sec^2 \alpha}{1 + \tan^2 \alpha} d \alpha = \int d \alpha = \alpha = \arctan x + C$$